# how can i pass parameters from javascript to hidden field in controls vb.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i have a control that has two `asp:HiddenField`

```
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="tabTitle" />
  <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="tabMenu" />
```

this control load in a page called `Alarms`

the control on the `alarms` page look like this

```
     <alarm:SubscriptionPanel ID="pnlSubscription" runat="server" />
```

what iam trying to do is passing value from page`alarms` to the `control hidden fields` and there is a function at the control code behind that reads the hidden fields values

*Question* is how can i pass javascript values to hidden field in controls `on page load`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JQuery for it like this

**Example :**

```
$("input[type=hidden][id='<%=tabTitle.ClientID%>']").val("Hello World"); 
$("input[type=hidden][id='<%=tabMenu.ClientID%>']").val("Hello World");
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this being that it is a valid alternative :/ I am upvoting this.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET 4.0 your best bet is to set the [`ClientIDMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) property on those controls to static and then simply use javascript to populate the hidden elements using plain ol' `document.getElementById()`. Something like this:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="tabTitle" ClientIDMode="Static" />


//since the id mode in the hidden element is static; 
//you should be able to do this safely:
document.getElementById('tabTitle').value = myvalue;
```

If you are not on ASP.NET 4.0; jQuery will help here since you can find an element using partial matching as HatSoft showed you in his answer but with a slight difference:

```
$("input[type=hidden][id*='tabTitle']").val("Hello World");
```

Note the `id*=` part. This gets all input elements whose ids contain the word `tabTitle`

Answer (score 2):

Besides the approach commented by @Icarus, you could expose a JavaScript function from your control.

The problem you would face if you use `ClientIDMode=Static` in that, you would be restricted to add only one `alarm:SubscriptionPanel` control to your page

If you are planning to use **only one control on each page, then the easiest approach is the one commented by @Icarus**, however I would consider it as a *temporal approach*

This alternative **encapsulates the logic where it really belongs, inside the custom control:**

#### Output

[image]

#### ASCX

```
<div id="<%: this.ClientID %>">
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden1" Value="one" />
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidden2" />
    <asp:Button Text="Post me" runat="server" OnClick="postme_Click" />
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lbl"></asp:Label>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var myObj = {
                setHidden1: function (myValue) {
                    $("#<%: this.hidden1.ClientID %>").val(myValue);
                },
                getHidden1: function () {
                    return $("#<%: this.hidden1.ClientID %>").val();
                },
                helloWorld: function () {
                    alert("hellow world");
                }
            };
            $("#<%: this.ClientID %>").data("data", myObj);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

#### ASCX code behind

```
    protected void postme_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.lbl.Text = "Posted: " + this.hidden1.Value;
    }
```

#### ASPX

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#myPageButton").click(function () {
                $("#<%: this.myControl.ClientID %>").data("data").setHidden1("plop");
                $("#<%: this.myControl2.ClientID %>").data("data").setHidden1("plop2");
            });
        });
    </script>
    <input type="button" id="myPageButton" value="Set Hidden value" />
    <uc1:EncapsulateJavaScriptLogicInUserControl ID="myControl" 
        runat="server" />
    <uc1:EncapsulateJavaScriptLogicInUserControl ID="myControl2" 
        runat="server" />
    <uc1:EncapsulateJavaScriptLogicInUserControl ID="myControl3" 
        runat="server" />
```

---

I just found another way, that looks even more object oriented, however, it requires you to use the Microsoft AJAX library.

#### ASCX

Change: `$("#<%: this.ClientID %>").data("data", myObj);`

Into: `$.extend($get("<%: this.ClientID %>"), myObj);`

#### ASPX

Change:

```
$("#<%: this.myControl.ClientID %>").data("data").setHidden1("plop");
$("#<%: this.myControl2.ClientID %>").data("data").setHidden1("plop2");
```

Into:

```
$get("<%: this.myControl.ClientID %>").setHidden1("plop");
$get("<%: this.myControl2.ClientID %>").setHidden1("plop2");
```

With this approach you remove the use of the `.data` jQuery function